# .NetCore 3 Web API: exclude model objects from controller response

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-3.0

I'm learning the basics of .NetCore 3 Web API and creating a basic app with it, and I'm stuck with this question.

I have a model with a foreign key that looks like this:

```c#
public class Rule
{
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public long CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Keyword { get; set; }
}
```

I can **POST** new Rules by just passing a `CategoryId` identifier. But when I do a **GET** request I get both the FK attribute (`CategoryId`) and the `Category` object that is referenced just for navigation purposes.
Request response example:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "categoryType": "Expense",
    "categoryId": 2,
    "category": null,
    "keyword": "TEST"
}
```

Is there an easy/quick way of excluding model elements from being exposed by the controller? Using DataAnnotations, Fluent API or just a service configuration?

By the way, I'm suing EFCore as well.

Thank you.

Comment: You can only get the `Category` object if you `Include` it or if it was loaded into the context before. How do you `Get` the `Rule`? (Code).

Comment: In this case, I want the Category object to be excluded from the json response.

Comment: Yeah, what I mean is: you caused the inclusion of the object yourself. EF won't do that spontaneously.

Comment: Are you using AutoMapper or some other mapping library, or no?

Answer (score 0):

A way is to create a manual JSON object using [JSON Convert](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
               id = rule.id,
               //more fields as needed...

            });
```